# Need to print out max value of an array and the name of which index holds the highest value

Tags: java, arrays

So the purpose of my program is to create an array for 5 Salespeople. The user is prompted to enter in the total sales for each Person. Then, I need to print out the sum, average, lowest sale and highest sale. I can get the average, the sum of all the sales, and have managed to print the largest value of the array, but I need it to say, for example, Salesperson 2 had $50,000 in sales. What I have now is "50,000 had $50,000" if that makes since. So value 3 of the array (salesperson 2, as I have not included a Salesperson 0) is 50,000. My array:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    final int SALESPEOPLE = 6;
    int[] sales = new int[SALESPEOPLE];
    int sum;

    for (int i = 1; i < sales.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter sales for salesperson " + i + ": ");
        sales[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }
}
```

And the get max value

```
for (int i = 1; i < sales.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(i + " \t" + sales[i]);
    sum += sales[i];
}

System.out.println("The highest sale was");
int maxValue = getMaxValue(sales);
int maxValueName = getMaxValueName(sales);
System.out.println("Name: " + maxValueName + "Sale: " + maxValue);

System.out.println("The lowest sale was");
int minValue = getMinValue(sales);
System.out.println(minValue);
```

Max Value

```
public static int getMaxValue(int[] array) {
    int maxValue = array[1];
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > maxValue) {
            maxValue = array[i];
        }
    }
    return maxValue;
}

public static int getMaxValueName(int[] array) {
    int maxValueName = array[1];
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > maxValueName) {
            maxValueName = array[i];
        }
    }
    return maxValueName;
}
```

Comment: Since the code of `getMaxValueName` is identical to `getMaxValue`, except with some variable names changed, of course it's going to return the same result.

Comment: In fact there is no place to store the names of the salespersons anywhere in the code originally shown here. It is impossible for the program to print data it never has.

Comment: The problem is I need to print out the Salesperson who had the largest sale in the array

Comment: @KieranHughes If you want `getMaxValueName` to return the "name" or ID number of the salesperson with the highest value, you'll have to fix it.  Right now, you set `maxValueName = array[i]` which means `maxValueName` will be holding the highest value (calling it a `Name` doesn't magically make the compiler find the name).  So if you want it to be a name instead of a value, how would you change the method?

Comment: Change the method getMaxValueName?

Answer (score 1):

You have some number of personnel in your sales force. Each of these persons has a name and also has made some amount of sales (some sort of a number). So it makes no sense to store just a number in your array.

Define a type of object that contains a String (for a person's name) and a number (for how much they sold). That is the kind of object you should put in your array. It makes no sense to write in Java and then not use anything that has even a hint of object-oriented design about it.

Notice that once you have an array of these objects, if you can find the object that has the highest sales number then you also have found the one that has the name of the person you want to print. Now ask yourself why you would want to write two separate functions, each of which has to search the array to find that object.

Comment: The amount sold is input by the user when the code is run. How can I print out just the value of the Array? so like, 1 50000 shows up, but I want it in proper format saying ("Salesperson " + maxName + "has $" + maxValue);

Comment: The program must also get each salesperson's name as input from the user somehow. If you never tell the program anyone's name, it cannot tell you the name of the biggest seller--unless your salespersons happened to be named "1", "2", "3", "4", and "5".

Comment: By the way, many years ago, in the Charlie Brown comic strip there was a character named 5 ...

Comment: So, I should make another array for 5 different names? Maybe if I post the question I'm trying to answer will help, as I don't think we're supposed to do that.
1)Find and print the maximum sale. Print both the id of the salesperson with the max sale and the amount of the
sale, e.g., “Salesperson 3 had the highest sale with $4500.” Note that you don’t need another loop for this; you can
do it in the same loop where the values are read and the sum is computed.

Comment: Aha, the source of confusion is the use of the word "name". You can still return two things at the same time (ID and sales number) from one function in Java by using an object. But one hardly ever just adds an object to output text in Java; instead, one reads smaller pieces of data from the object and puts those pieces in the desired place in the output text.

Comment: @DavidK I think that was just his nickname (wasn't his full name 555 35798 or something?)  :-)  (It's pretty bad that I'm old enough to remember this.)

Comment: @ajb I think the same on all counts (there's a wiki page about him at http://peanuts.wikia.com/wiki/555_95472), though I'm not old enough to have read the strip when he was first introduced (in 1963), just old enough to have seen him later.